# Spring JPA Repository - Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: spring, jpa, repository

I have a Repository and hitting directly this repository from Postman.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2115)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1898)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1874)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2610)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2593)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2422)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2417)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1980)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:102)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 98 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=RCON411.PROJECT, DRIVER=4.11.69
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:676)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jn.c(jn.java:2561)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jn.d(jn.java:2549)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jn.a(jn.java:2025)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.a(kn.java:6836)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.g(cb.java:140)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.a(cb.java:40)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.q.a(q.java:32)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.rb.i(rb.java:135)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jn.ib(jn.java:1996)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.sc(kn.java:3058)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.b(kn.java:3841)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.fc(kn.java:702)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.executeQuery(kn.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:82)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
    ... 127 common frames omitted
```

Project class is

```
@Data @Entity @Table(name = "PROJECT", schema = "DCS") public class Project implements Identifiable<Integer> {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PRJ_I", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "PRJ_NM")
    private String projectName;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PRJ_I")
    private CcpaCustomerProjectGroup ccpaCustomerProjectGroup;
}
```

CcpaCustomerProjectGroup is

```
@Data @Entity @Table(name = "CCPA_CUS_PRJ_GRP", schema = "DCS") public class CcpaCustomerProjectGroup implements Identifiable<Integer> {
    @Id
    @Column(name="CCPA_CUS_PRJ_GRP_I")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="CUS_PRJ_GRP_I")
    private Integer customerProjectGroupId;

    @Column(name="PRJ_I")
    private Integer projectId;

    /*@OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Project project;*/
}
```

ProjectRepository is

```
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Integer>,JpaSpecificationExecutor<Project>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Project> {

    @Query(value="select p.PRJ_I,p.PRJ_NM from CCPA_CUS_PRJ_GRP c,project p where c.CUS_PRJ_GRP_I = ?1 and c.PRJ_I = p.PRJ_I and p.PRJ_NM like ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Project> find(@Param("clientId") Integer clientId, @Param("projectName") String projectName);

}
```

Comment: Google for SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704. This error means that the table PROJECT doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated by JB in the comments, this is the important part of the stack trace:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=RCON411.PROJECT, DRIVER=4.11.69

First confirm that DCS.PROJECT exists in the datasource you are working with, and that the user you are connecting with in your application has the necessary grants to view it.

Similarly, Looks like the PROJECT table might be trying to get accessed from the wrong schema. Does the user you are using to connect to DB2 in your app have access to the DCS schema? And if so, you may need to set the CURRENT_SCHEMA to be DCS.

Comment: List<Project> findByProjectNameIgnoreCaseContaining(@Param("projectName") String projectName);
is the another methos that I have in same repository and able to get the data for given Project name.